# laravel 6 - how to sort by column in a foreign table

Tags: laravel, sorting, sql-order-by, relationship

I'm sorry if this has been answered to death, but for a week I cannot figure out how to get this to work.
I'm using Laravel 6, and I have 3 tables

Facts
id
fact

Likes
id
fact_id

Dislikes
id
fact_id

I've created one to many relationships between the Fact model and the Like / Dislike models. I'm having issues trying to query all 3 tables, and sort the results descending by the total amount of rows from the likes table.

This is the query I am using to at least be able to get all the information from each table

```
$facts = \App\Fact::with(['likes', 'dislikes'])->paginate(25);
```

But i am completely lost on how to get it to sort in desc order, for the likes table.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I have left out information, I will reply right away with it.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're looking to sort the `facts` records by number of `likes`, you'll have to use a `join()`; `with()` doesn't modify the query it's associated with, it simply includes them as a property `foreach ($facts as $fact){ $fact->likes // or $fact->dislikes }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withCount` for that

```
$facts = Fact::with(['likes', 'dislikes'])
    ->withCount('likes')
    ->orderByDesc('likes_count')
    ->paginate(25);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: My god, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much as this will now help me going forward to adjust the results as I need. Now i can spent hopefully half the time to read and see why this works for me, and why I wasn't finding the proper results to begin with.